# X-ray mode does not work correctly. How to do it right?

Tags: three.js

I'm new to three.js. I am trying to make an x-ray effect with a loaded stl model

I have this code:

```
   const materialCameraPosition = this.camera.position.clone();

        const customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
            {
                uniforms: {
                    "c": { value: 1.0 },
                    "p": { value: 3 },
                    glowColor: ({ value: new THREE.Color("#000000") }),
                    viewVector: ({ value: materialCameraPosition }),
                    vertexShader: `uniform vec3 viewVector;
                    uniform float c;
                    uniform float p;
                    varying float intensity;
                    void main()
                    {
                        vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
                        vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
                        intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );
            
                        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
                    }` as any,
                    fragmentShader: `uniform vec3 glowColor;
                    varying float intensity;
                    void main()
                    {
                        vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
                        gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
                    }` as any,
                },
                side: THREE.FrontSide,
                blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
                transparent: true,
                // opacity: 0.5,
                depthWrite: false
            });



        this.object!.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                console.log(child);
                child.material = customMaterial;
            }
        })
```

It works, but incorrectly.
I would like to get a transparent glow based on the color of my model, but I get pink color.
glowColor doesn't work no matter how I change it.
Unfortunately, I can't share the rest of the code but my model is

```
object: THREE.Object3D;
```

What should I pay attention to?
Many thanks.

Comment: Seems you've got wrong structure of parameters for ShaderMaterial: `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader` properties included in `uniforms`, that is wrong.

Comment: Yes, thanks.
You can write this as an answer and I will mark it.